# Using Pandas to get a certain string from a row in different excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with different sheets, each sheet containing cities names with some data. For example:

```
Istanbul  Paris Barcelona
1          2        3
4          2        6
```

In every sheet, I want to extract the row for each cell where Paris = 2. 
So far, I have :

```
import pandas
xls= pandas.ExcelFile('cities.xlsx')
sheets= xls.sheet_names
print sheets
#Dialogue Result
for row in sheets.iter_rows():
   row = sheet.row("Paris")
   print row.index()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `pd.concat`

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
alldf=pd.concat([xls.parse(x) for x in xls.sheet_names],keys=xls.sheet_names)

alldf.loc[alldf.Paris==2,:]
```

Comment: Or possibly... `pd.concat([df for name, df in pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xls', sheet_name=None)])`...

Comment: @JonClements yep , this can achieve it as well :-), thank you man, but for me I would like keep the sheets name as an addition index here. :-)

Comment: No worries... I suppose then move out the `dfs = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xls', sheet_name=None)`, and then `pd.concat(list(dfs.values()), keys=list(dfs))` ?